# How to identify an internet hog?

Tags: wireless-networking, wireshark

Our small office network will occasionally slow when a coworker starts a large download or a large file transfer between an in-house server and their local machine.

How can I identify this hog on my network by IP or client device name or really any way so I can go to their desk and give them a USB stick instead?

Answer (score 0):

If you have a real switch in your network, you can access the switch and check the interface statistics such as packet rate and total packets in/out. And then you can trace from the interface to the device attached to it.

IMO, if the server is in-house and not in WAN, you should just upgrade your switch. They are very cheap.

(Edit: I noticed that you tagged wireless-networking. If you use Wi-Fi, the wireless AP may have interface to inform you which client uses the most data. There are also ways to enable some sort of QoS on the Wi-Fi)